# Uncaught ReferenceError: function not defined at onclick

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm receiving an 'Uncaught Reference Error: function(e.g upButton()) is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick'. I have a simple canvas game from a tutorial I followed which uses keyboard controls to move, however I wanted buttons too.

I always do a test page to make sure that everything's working fine, which it did, before I move it all to my main html file, however although I have literally copied and pasted my code from one file to the other it's giving me this error.

The html button code:

```
<button onclick="upButton()">Up</button>
<button onclick="downButton()">Down</button>
<button onclick="leftButton()">Left</button>
<button onclick="rightButton()">Right</button>
```

My javascript function code:

```
function upButton() {
    character.y -= 15;
}

function downButton() {
    character.y += 15;
}

function leftButton() {
    character.x -= 15;
}

function rightButton() {
    character.x += 15;
}
```

From the fact that my test html file works, I thought that everything was defined correctly, and that it was calling this function correctly too, so I am unaware on why this is happening.

Full html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CS25320</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <!-- Image from https://matthewboyz.deviantart.com/art/Blue-flat-wallpaper-555483912 -->
    <body background="background.png">

        <div id="header">
            <h1>Mystical Mountains Game</h1>
            <p>CS25320 / Programming for the Web</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/about.html"><b>About</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/help.html"><b>Help</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <br>
        </div>
        <p id="health"></p>
        <p id="health2"></p>
        <p id="health3"></p>
        <p id="health4"></p>

        <button onclick="upButton()">Up</button>
        <button onclick="downButton()">Down</button>
        <button onclick="leftButton()">Left</button>
        <button onclick="rightButton()">Right</button>

        <script src="thegame.js"></script>

        <div id="footer">
            <h3>Disclaimer</h3>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Full js code:

```
//Create Canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 450;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Background image 
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function() {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "background4.png";

//Character image
var charReady = false;
var charImage = new Image();
charImage.onload = function() {
    charReady = true;
};
charImage.src = "character2.png";

//Jewel image
var jewelReady = false;
var jewelImage = new Image();
jewelImage.onload = function() {
    jewelReady = true;
};
jewelImage.src = "jewel.png";

//Game objects
var character = {
    speed: 256, // movement in pixels per second
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

var jewel = { // Doesn't move so just has coordinates
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};

var jewelsCaught = 0; // Stores number of jewel caught

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

//Buttons for cross-compatibility with other devices 
//I have added in this code to allow the user to use buttons
function upButton() {
    character.y -= 15;
}

function downButton() {
    character.y += 15;
}

function leftButton() {
    character.x -= 15;
}

function rightButton() {
    character.x += 15;
}

//Reset the game when the character catches a troll or jewel
var reset = function() {
    character.x = canvas.width / 2;
    character.y = canvas.height / 2;

    //Throw jewel on screen randomly
    jewel.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    jewel.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};

//Update game objects
var update = function(modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        character.y -= character.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        character.y += character.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        character.x -= character.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        character.x += character.speed * modifier;
    }

    //Are they touching?
    if (
        character.x <= (jewel.x + 52)
        && jewel.x <= (character.x + 52)
        && character.y <= (jewel.y + 52)
        && jewel.y <= (character.y + 52)
    ) {

        ++jewelsCaught;
        reset();
    }
};

//Draw everything
var render = function() {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
    if (charReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(charImage, character.x, character.y);
    }
    if (jewelReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(jewelImage, jewel.x, jewel.y);
    }

    //Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
    ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Jewels caught: " + jewelsCaught, 32, 32);
};

var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (jewelsCaught <= 5) {
        document.getElementById("health").innerHTML = "Health: *";
    }
    else if (jewelsCaught >= 6) {
        document.getElementById("health2").innerHTML = "Health: **";
    }
    else if (jewelsCaught >= 11 && jewelsCaught <= 15) {
        document.getElementById("health3").innerHTML = "Health: ***";
    }
    else if (jewelsCaught >= 16 && jewelsCaught <= 20) {
        document.getElementById("health4").innerHTML = "Health: ****";
    }
}

//Main game loop
var main = function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    //How many milliseconds have passed since the last interval
    var delta = now - then; 

    update(delta / 1000);
    //Record the timestamp
    render();

    then = now;

    //Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

//Cross-brower support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

//Play game
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

Comment: where is your js function code written, i cannot see in full js code?

Comment: I've provided the snipped of the button function in js, and right at the bottom is my js code. In the end I've decided to ditch my previous page and instead use the test html code as my main page. I still don't know why this was happening to the above code though

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the code is already included to the page. For you full html code, I cannot find your javascript function code, `upButton`, `downButton`, `leftButton` and `rightButton`. It is no problem for the following code snippet.

```js
//file: thegame.js
//Create Canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 450;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Background image 
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function() {
 bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "background4.png";

//Character image
var charReady = false;
var charImage = new Image();
charImage.onload = function() {
 charReady = true;
};
charImage.src = "character2.png";

//Jewel image
var jewelReady = false;
var jewelImage = new Image();
jewelImage.onload = function() {
 jewelReady = true;
};
jewelImage.src = "jewel.png";

//Game objects
var character = {
 speed: 256, // movement in pixels per second
 x: 0,
 y: 0
};

function upButton() {
 character.y -= 15;
}

function downButton() {
 character.y += 15;
}

function leftButton() {
 character.x -= 15;
}

function rightButton() {
 character.x += 15;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CS25320</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <!-- Image from https://matthewboyz.deviantart.com/art/Blue-flat-wallpaper-555483912 -->
    <body background="background.png">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Mystical Mountains Game</h1>
            <p>CS25320 / Programming for the Web</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/about.html"><b>About</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="http://users.aber.ac.uk/lid15/cs25320/coursework/help.html"><b>Help</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <br>
        </div>
        <p id="health"></p>
        <p id="health2"></p>
        <p id="health3"></p>
        <p id="health4"></p>
        <button onclick="upButton()">Up</button>
        <button onclick="downButton()">Down</button>
        <button onclick="leftButton()">Left</button>
        <button onclick="rightButton()">Right</button>
        <!-- include in code snippet -->
        <!-- <script src="thegame.js"></script> -->
        <div id="footer">
            <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```